# Forcing SVN working copy into 'cleanup required' state

Tags: svn, working-copy

I have some code that works with Subversion, and I want to test stability in case the working copy is in a 'cleanup required' state.

How do I reliably force the working copy into this state (for tests)?

Comment: What do you mean by _"'cleanup required' state"_? 
If you need to make sure you remove locks and update status of all files, you can simply run the command `svn cleanup`.

Comment: @tripu I want to get into a state when any operation fails with a 'locked, cleanup required' message (I don't remember the exact message it gives when it needs cleanup).

Comment: This is funny. I've managed to lock my local copies many times for different reasons (and managed to get them working again via `svn cleanup` or sometimes working a bit more).

But now that you ask how to do it _on purpose_, I realise I don't have a quick answer :(

I believe you can run many commands, eg `svn up` and immediately kill the Subversion process. That should create special lock files within Subversion's hidden directory, and put your local copy in a _faulty_ state -- one that would require running `svn cleanup`. I think!

Comment: @tripu I would like something I can reliably run in automated tests -- killing `svn up` feels like something that may or may not work depending on timing. Unless there is an easy way to block `svn up`?

Comment: No, you're absolutely right: killing the process programmatically would be unreliable (and not an elegant solution at all). I'll look into it if I find some time!